# How to launch an existing Heroku app under different URLs

Tags: heroku, copy, slug

If you want to copy your existing production Heroku-hosted app (e.g., https://myappname.herokuapp.com) and launch it under alternate URLs (e.g., https://myappname01.herokuapp.com, https://myappname02.herokuapp.com, etc.), you can do the following:

1. Login to your remote Heroku account and add several alternate target apps. The example below targets 4 alternate apps (named myappname01, myappname02, myappname03, myappname04).
2. Under your local Heroku Git repo for your source app, launch Git Bash and run the following cloneSlug.sh script (just change 'myappname' argument to the name of your existing source app).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#PURPOSE:    Copy an existing production Heroku slug to 4 alternate URLs, using the Heroku Platform API. 
#MORE INFO:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-copying-slugs
#USAGE:      ./cloneSlug.sh myappname 2>/dev/null


APPNAME=$1
SLUG_ID=$(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" -n https://api.heroku.com/apps/${APPNAME}/releases | tail -15 | awk '/"slug"/,/"id"/' | grep '"id":' | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's/"//g')

#Example: the output of the above curl is the entire version history of the app in the form of JSON text data obtained from your Heroku account (see below). 
#Next, we feed the last 15 lines of that data to awk to isolate consecutive lines having properties "slug" & "id", inclusive. 
#From those lines, we isolate the "id" line and parse it to isolate the raw slug ID string.
#  :
#  :
#  {
#    "addon_plan_names":[],
#    "app":{
#      "id":"c9bff57f-bb82-4742-ab66-79ea8eb98c6c",
#      "name":"myappname"
#    },
#    "created_at":"2020-03-21T21:29:47Z",
#    "description":"Deploy 559ab324",
#    "status":"succeeded",
#    "id":"768f3f32-a367-430f-a493-86d1395f20f1",
#    "slug":{
#      "id":"7d3af19-5ac9-4a80-93ac-f1a49af4e75a"
#    },
#    "updated_at":"2020-03-21T21:29:47Z",
#    "user":{
#      "email":"youremail@gmail.com",
#      "id":"1fe9f387-fdcf-4776-85a6-2ffd19f2bd57"
#    },
#    "version":43,
#    "current":true,
#    "output_stream_url":null
#  }


#Once we have SLUG_ID, pass it to the following curl to ask Heroku to copy that slug over to 4 other app slugs.
for i in {1..4}
do  
    echo -n "copying ${APPNAME} to ${APPNAME}0$i ..."
    curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" -n -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"slug": "'${SLUG_ID}'"}' https://api.heroku.com/apps/${APPNAME}0$i/releases | grep 'status' | sed 's/"//g; s/,$//'
done

#The result is that the same app can be launched using 5 different URLs.  Example:
# https://myappname.herokuapp.com
# https://myappname01.herokuapp.com
# https://myappname02.herokuapp.com
# https://myappname03.herokuapp.com
# https://myappname04.herokuapp.com
```